# How to set a return set's data to null and run a different select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

### Background:

I have a select statement where I return each row. That in itself is basic, but where I am having issues is that if a column in the row reads *DENIED*, all data should now be set to null for all rows, and I need to return a whole new set of data.

### What I have tried:

I have been trying to handle this via a case statement inside the select statement. This doesn't seem to do what I want as the case statement is erroring out. From what I understand, trying to run a difference select statement or a stored procedure is not allowed.

### Question:

I am unsure how to formulate a query that does this. Is a case statement the right way to go? Would temp tables help?

### Desired results:

If all rows have a *status* of *SUBMITTED*:

- 1, 222, 'Info', 'SUBMITTED'
- 2, 333, 'More Info', 'SUBMITTED'

If at least one row has *DENIED* as its *status*

- null, null, data from a different select statement, 'SUBMITTED'
- null, null, data from a different select statement, 'DENIED'

### Code:

```
Select 
    id,
    licence,
    genericInfo,
    case
    when status = 'SUBMITTED' then
        status
    when status = 'DENIED' then
        'DENIED - Do stuff'
    end as 'Results'
from genericTable
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have posted?

Comment: Two approaches: select data into a temp table or variable first and use `IF EXISTS` to conditionally return one result or another, or duplicate the query (in a CTE or suchlike) and use a `UNION ALL` with `WHERE EXISTS` / `WHERE NOT EXISTS` on the parts to do it all in one query. What's going to be more efficient depends.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: you can have stuff like IF EXISTS([sql to detect denied]) storedProc1 ELSE storedProc2;  Is that where you are trying to go?  Since any DENIED record seems to imply a different action (from what you said in comments to answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep "Submitted" records intact and modify "Denied" records?

Setup:

```
Create Table genericTable
(
id Int,
licence Int,
genericInfo VarChar(50),
status VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into genericTable Values 
(1,222,'Info','SUBMITTED'),
(2,333,'Info','SUBMITTED'),
(3,444,'More Info','DENIED')
```

TSQL

```
   Select * From genericTable Where status = 'SUBMITTED'
   Union All
   Select NULL,NULL,NULL,'DENIED - Do Stuff' From genericTable Where [status] = 'DENIED'
```

Result

```
id  licence     genericInfo status
1       222     Info        SUBMITTED
2       333     Info        SUBMITTED
NULL    NULL    NULL        DENIED - Do Stuff
```

Comment: wow realyy good and simple, it seems that i did not understand the quation with null null null. Good work

Answer (score 1):

since the pivotal thing is if ANY record is 'DENIED', then build your data in a CTE and return it as normal if no DENIED exists, but if there is any DENIED, return it with NULLs in it.

Since EXISTS and NOT EXISTS are mutually exclusive, you whould always get one or the other output, but never both

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (Select 
            id,
            licence,
            genericInfo,
            status
            from genericTable
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT C2.* FROM CTE C2 WHERE C2.status = 'DENIED')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null id, null licence, null genericinfo, c3.status 
            FROM CTE c3 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT C4.* FROM CTE C4 WHERE C4.status = 'DENIED')
```

I've done this with UNION, but I will only ever return one half of the UNION

Comment: taking a look at this answer and reading your other comments, I have gone the route of using an if exists and it has gotten me to almost what I need, and that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know if i understood you right.
a select statment in case stats is bad for performace, but its still possible.
here is a test.

```
Select 
    id,
    licence,
    genericInfo,
    case
    when (select count(*) from genericTable where status = 'DENIED') <= 0 and status = 'SUBMITTED' then
        status
    when (select count(*) from genericTable where status = 'DENIED') > 0  then
        'DENIED - Do stuff'
    end as 'Results'
from genericTable
```

did i understand you right ?

Comment: That's pretty close to the idea. I'm already able to determine if there if a *Denied* in the row. What I am having issues with is running a different stored procedure or select statement inside of the *then* portion  when a *Denied* is found

Comment: if you look at the first case when you will se that i validate that when status = 'SUBMITTED' and also a diffrent select stats at the beggining so it is possible. but you should switch between them so status = 'SUBMITTED' and then your select statement it should work as you which. but im not sure about stopreprecedure. you will have to do a while loop and do you statement there insted with if and else

Comment: @TGills - I think you might be thinking of SQL select statements in a similar way to program logic and flow control?  You can use program logic in TSQL language though, not normally encased in a single SQL SELECT command - you can use IF to use the results of queries to decide if you 'do stuff'